# Will this code work on Jenkins without any problems?

Tags: svn, jenkins

If the URL does not have a specific folder, will this code cause an error in Jenkins?

```
@echo off
set tempTagFolderName=TempTag/
set trunkFolderName=trunk/
set tempTagPath=https://raptorjung/svn/SvnTempTest/branches/TempTag/
set branchPath=https://raptorjung/svn/SvnTempTest/branches/
set trunkPath=https://raptorjung/svn/SvnTempTest/trunk/
set headPath=https://raptorjung/svn/SvnTempTest/

svn info %tempTagPath% > NUL 2>&1

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    svn del %tempTagPath% -m "Remove the TempTag"
) else (
    echo [Notice]TempTag does not exist so creates new one...
)

svn list %trunkPath% > NUL 2>&1

if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    svn cp %trunkPath% %tempTagPath% -m "Move trunk to TempTag in branches"
) else (
    echo Trunk does not exist, therefore exit the program
    end
)

pause
```

Comment: What about giving it a try?

Comment: Your qestion is unclear. Please consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question.